# How to execute a script within another script with other credentials than admin

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that runs as admin, the problem being that part of the script needs to be run as another standard user.
My idea was the following:
to have a second script, which will be run inside the first one, with parameters allowing to run it as another user

Here is what I tried:

```
$username = 'domainusername'
$password = 'password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process powershell 'C:Software\script_executed_as_user.ps1' -Credential $credential
```

but it doesn't execute correctly (no error message)
does anyone has a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

By refactoring your `Start-Process` line, we can see the error message:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-command &{C:Software\script_executed_as_user.ps1}" -Credential $credential
```

this opens up a new window and forces the window to stay open.

I get a window with the message

> C:Software\script_executed_as_user.ps1 : The term 'C:Software\script_executed_as_user.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
> that the path is correct and try again.

The problem is you are missing a \ in your path:

```
C:Software\script_executed_as_user.ps1
```

should be

```
C:\Software\script_executed_as_user.ps1
```